# SSH and Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I would like to access a SSH server from an app which I'd like to create with javascript in Phonegap/Cordova. I am using the PhoneGap App in IOS and Android. I have seen there is cdv-ssh-plugin, but this only allows to transfer files. I'd like to execute commands and have access to stdin, stdout and stderr.
What plugin can I use?

TIA

Comment: As far as i know there isn't one been looking for a while.  Might start one for a project but android would be the only platform i would support.

Comment: Sounds good. Keep me informed.